# how to fill the values in form, data generated from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

how to fill textfield with the data which i'm getting via ajax in the textfield, what code i worte is doing this, it's not replacling the value already enterend by the user, suppose user wants to write "autocomplete" and he wrote "au" now the html will show hint as "autocomplete" now when user clicks my textfield looks like this "au,autocomplete" but it should show "autocomplete" how to resolve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sku').keyup(function(){
        var len = $('#sku').val().length;
        if(len >= 2)
        {
            var value = $('#sku').val();
            $.post(
                '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/testing/autocomplete',
                {sku:value},
                function(data){
                    $('#feedback').html(data);
                }
            );
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click','p',function(){
        $('#sku').val(this.id+',');
    });
});
</script>
<input type="text" name="sku" placeholder="SKU1,SKU2,SKU3" id="sku"/>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly in you should set textfield that you are typing into.

```
 function(data){
                $('#sku').text(data);
            }
```

assuming that data returned is string.